# Cannot install wine

Tags: wine

I'am new to Linux and just installed Elementary os. Now I want to install wine but get this message:

Package dependencies cannot be resolved This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time. the following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine:

I already tried a lot of commands in the terminal wich I found on the internet and here in other questions like sudo **add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine** but it still doens't want to install.

my systeem is 64 bit quadcore Intel i3 2350M cpu 2.30Ghz Memory 3,8 Gb Graphics: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Answer (score 1):

Try **sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386** in terminal.

Comment: I tried and after that I tried again to install wine but this is what I get the following packages have unmet dependencies:

wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-amd64 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but it is a virtual package

Comment: Try this, open terminal and use this commands: **sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386**, **sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds**,  **sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel**

Comment: this is what happens when I use this command in terminal:
dpkg: error: architecture 'i386,' is illegal: character `,' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-')

Comment: So I tried leaving the  ,  out but also no results

Comment: q4wine: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is to be installed
        Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
        Depends: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1+elementary3~ubuntu0.3.1 is to be installed
        Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1+elementary3~ubuntu0.3.1 is to be installed

Comment: There is more but I cannot put it here because of too much characters

Comment: Try **sudo apt-get install wine1.7**

Comment: unfortenally    no succes:
E: Unable to locate package wine1.7
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wine1.7'

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install wine is using PlayOnLinux.

https://www.playonlinux.com/en/

It's easy and you can choose which version of wine you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have intalled virtual box to work with Sony Vegas in Windows.
I understand that it is even safer this way than installing Wine.
I dont know if I stay satisfied when i have to reactivated windows in virtual box again and again.